# Conditional concatenation of python pandas dataframe (sql join on self)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

**[Aim]**
We have an existing dataframe and wish to extract a series of records and concat (sql join on self) given a condition in one command OR in another DataFrame.

**[Situation]**
Python version: 3.3.3
Pandas version: 0.15.1

We have a sizeable DataFrame with 10,000+ rows. This is just an example to understand the logic.

DataFrame1 -> df1:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,1],
                    'B': [1,4,1,2],
                    'C': ['test1','test2','test3','test4']
                    })

Resulting in:
    A  B      C
    1  1  test1
    2  4  test2
    3  1  test3
    1  2  test4
    5  8  test5
```

**[Expected output]**
We are looking to output:

- All columns A, B, C where: B = 1 -> output = df1[df1['B'] == 1]
- Add to output all of those where 
   
  output['A'] == df1['A']
   AND
   df1['B'] == 2

Thus:

```
A  B      C
1  1  test1
3  1  test3
1  2  test4
```

It would be awesome to show the most pythonic/ pandanic (sounds weird) way of doing this :)

Comment: did you attempt to try anything?

Comment: Yes, We can retrieve the data from both and then concat them:
out1 = df1[df1['B'] == 1]
out2 = df1[df1['B'] == 2]

But maybe I should have specified that I have a sizeable DataFrame of 10,000 rows+. I mean technically we could do a for loop but I'm sure there is a neater way to do this with some cool DataFrame functionality (concat/ merge/ join -> i just don't see the conditional join). Normally I would join a SQL table on itself given a condition but for some reason I don't see it in this situation

Comment: We could do something like this given the out1 and out2 above: result = pd.merge(out1, out2, left_on='A', right_on='A', how='left') but here we merged columns. I'd like to do a result = pd.concat(out1, out2, left_on='A', right_on='A', how='left')  but this obviously results in an error..

Comment: @Mark I've just modified my answer. Let me know whether that works for you.

Comment: @JianxunLi I also commented your answer :). Yeah it seems to work but I just cannot seem to grasp why we have all this nice nifty functionality for merging columns but not for rows :/

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether there is a better way, but the following works. The idea is to use `.isin` operator for your 2nd condition. The final boolean selector is a `or` combination of 1st condition and 2nd condition.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# your data
# =============================
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,1],
                    'B': [1,4,1,2],
                    'C': ['test1','test2','test3','test4']
                    })
print(df1)


   A  B      C
0  1  1  test1
1  2  4  test2
2  3  1  test3
3  1  2  test4

# processing
# =====================================
mask = df1.B == 1

df1[mask | ((df1.A.isin(df1[mask].A)) & (df1.B==2))]


   A  B      C
0  1  1  test1
2  3  1  test3
3  1  2  test4
```

Comment: Yes that may work but I find it a bit strange that we don't have a conditional concat, or append or something similar to the merge functionality but then for appending rows: like this (will return a nasty error ofc): pd.concat(out1, out2, left_on='A', right_on='A', how='left')

Comment: @Mark look at that boolean selector inside `[]`, the first part `mask` refers to the first condition, the second part `.isin` tells us whether for a particular row `A` is in the previous mask and `df1.B==2` are simultaneously achieved. I wrote this way because you ask for a 'pandanic' solution...

Comment: Yes it works :). But with 'pandanic' i meant something as nice and elegant to use as the merge function but instead of merging on rows we merge columns. Following that, I'd say we concat but I don't have the merge functionality in the concat function :(

Answer (score 0):

First off

```
df['A'] == output['A']
```

will fail unless because of a length mismatch, unless all the values in B are 1. On the other hand,

```
df['A'][df.B == 1] == output['A']
```

Is guaranteed to be all `True` as it's tantamount to saying `x == x`. It's completely redundant. All you need do here is

```
df[(df.B.isin([1, 2])]
```

Comment: Yes that works when we are looking for any in the set that is of value 1,2. But, we are looking for all of the records B = 1  and B = 2 where A = A. In our set we sometimes could have this: B = 2 but no B = 1. We thus want to exclude these. As such the isin() doesn't seem to apply?

Comment: It is like a flow. First we find all A,B where B = 1  then we find all where B = 2 and matches with A.

Comment: It's the same thing. A single record can't satisfy B = 1 and B = 2, it has to be one or the other. And A = A is a tautology, i.e. it's always True. Unless there is something you want to do with the subset satisfying just B == 1 then there is no need to do it in two steps. The problem is as simple as getting all rows where B is 1 or 2, unless I'm missing something, but from you're example that's what it looks like.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion. Our set can sometimes contain for example A=10, B=2, but NO A=10, B=1. As B=1 was not in the set we want to exclude it.

Comment: So you're saying that you only include rows with A equal to a certain value if there are two rows with A equal to that value, one with B = 1 and one with B = 2?

Comment: Yeah. To give an example: in a given time period we have userid 'A'. If in the given period B = 1, then take all B n for user A. In other words, if the user had one purchase B = 1 in the period, then return me all of his purchases. But if in the given period his purchase count is B =3 and in the same period there is no B = 1, then we exclude him.

Comment: Will you please read over your comments before you post them. They are really hard to understand and have grammatical errors. Also, you haven't mentioned anything about time periods or purchase counts before now. Also, this contradicts your expected output, which contains the row with A = 3 despite there being only one row with A = 3, rather than two with B = 1 and B = 2. I give up!